# Оптимизатор на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s = input()
    if '#' in s:
        s=s[:s.find('#')]
    s=s.rstrip()
    print(s)
```

Пока только так...

Помогите написать код который:

- если следуют несколько пробелов подряд не в начале строки, то нужно
  оставить только один пробел;
- если встретился символ комментария #, то его и всё, что за ним,
  выводить не нужно;
- если лишние пробелы или символ комментария встретились внутри
  (одинарных) кавычек, то ничего убирать или менять в них не надо;
- если после кавычки встретилась ещё одна кавычка, то она закрывает
  первую лишь в том случае, если перед ней не стоит обратный слэш, не
  экранированный другим обратным слэшем (гарантируется, что за
  пределами кавычек и комментариев обратный слэш не встречается).

Comment: Попробуйте более информативные заголовки использовать, более специфичные для вашей задачи [ask]